# How to pass-through local machine's mounted network drive to podman?

Tags: docker, mount, podman

I created a podman for Jellyfin using the [official instructions](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/administration/installing.html#podman):

> Install Podman:
>
> ```
> sudo dnf install -y podman
> ```
>
> Create and run a Jellyfin container:
>
> ```
> podman run \
> --detach \
> --label "io.containers.autoupdate=registry" \
> --name myjellyfin \
> --publish 8096:8096/tcp \
> --rm \
> --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
> --userns keep-id \
> --volume jellyfin-cache:/cache:Z \
> --volume jellyfin-config:/config:Z \
> docker.io/jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
> ```
>
> Open the necessary ports in your machine's firewall if you wish to
> permit access to the Jellyfin server from outside the host. This is
> not done automatically when using rootless Podman. If your
> distribution uses firewalld, the following commands save and load a
> new firewall rule opening the HTTP port 8096 for TCP connections.
>
> ```
> sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=8096/tcp --permanent
> sudo firewall-cmd --reload
> ```

I would like to then have `myjellyfin` be able to read and write the network drive I've mounted on the local machine: `/var/mnt/Media/`. I'm new to containers, but found [podman-mount](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-mount.1.html) which does the reverse of what I want so I'm hoping there's a similar command to get what I want.

How can I get `myjellyfin` to be able to read and write to the Host's `/var/mnt/Media/`?

Comment: You use `-v` (`--volume`) to mount a host directory inside your container: `podman run -v /var/mnt/Media:/path/inside/container ...`. This is called a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as follows:

```
podman run \
--detach \
--label "io.containers.autoupdate=registry" \
--name myjellyfin \
--publish 8096:8096/tcp \
--rm \
--user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
--userns keep-id \
--volume jellyfin-cache:/cache:Z \
--volume jellyfin-config:/config:Z \
--volume /var/mnt/Media:/media:Z \            # Add this line
docker.io/jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
```